# Is there a difference between Netbean's Swing Extensions Library and javax.swing?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I did some googling, but I couldn't find anything specifically that answers my questions. I wanted to know the difference between them and the pros and cons of each.

Comment: *"the pros and cons of each"* .. *"Swing Extensions Library.."* Has a dependency on Swing *"..and javax.swing?"*  Does not include everything in the extensions library.  That much I can guess just from the name 'Swing Extensions Library', BTW.  Never heard of it before now.  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GroupLayout, which has been developed for NetBeans' Matisse GUI builder, has been added to Java SE 6. If you're using an earlier JDK version you need the original non-standard library (not javax.swing-package).

Also see: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormSwingLayoutLibrary

Comment: Is one newer than the other? I'm unclear if there is a difference.

Comment: If you use JDK 6 or greater it's recommended to use the JDK version as it is standard.

Comment: You should put the link in your answer and quote it too. +1 and best answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually i am not completely sure, but i think there is no difference between this two , and nebeans uses the JDK installed in our pc. but  netbeans provide some design flexibility.

Comment: I asked because it seems that I have to share the Swing Extension Library when compiling because of a class used in there.

Comment: no you don't need to do so. because there is no extra extension in netBeans.

Comment: Abu, that's false. If I am calling the class `org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout` which is used in the NetBeans then I have to share the library. I can either use javax.swing's GroupLayout in Java 6 or NetBean's Swing Library. I would have to change the code if I switch the library.